# mongodb. background index and lock collection?

Tags: mongodb

Please tell me if I will use background index

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ a: 1 }, {background: true})
```

my collection not locked when several insert is doing?

Comment: When you set the background flag to true, there is no locks while building the index. You can read more about it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/

Answer (score 2):

There are no long-term locks held while building an index in background on the a single node. However on a replica-set you have to be careful on how the index build happens on different nodes of the replica-set.

**MongoDB v2.4 or lower version**
- Background build triggered on Primary replica results in foreground index build on the Secondary replica and will be blocking operation on the secondary
- To avoid the foreground build on the secondary, suggested way to build indices in replica-set is to do a rolling index build. You can find more details about it at http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/

**MongoDB 2.5 or higher version**
On the latest available versions of MongoDB (v2.6) the background index build on Primary replica will be background on the Secondary replica as well.

Apart from locking, index building is RAM / CPU / Disk intensive operation and pressure on these resources may vary based on the dataset. I would recommend doing index builds at relatively quiet time in production environments.

Answer (score 0):

This section from the Mongo manual provides direct answer, if your version is 4.2 or greater.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/core/index-creation/#std-label-index-operations-replicated-build

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, index builds obtain an exclusive lock on only the collection being indexed during the start and end of the build process to protect metadata changes. The rest of the build process uses the yielding behavior of background index builds to maximize read-write access to the collection during the build. 4.2 index builds still produce efficient index data structures despite the more permissive locking behavior.

There's also a section covering previous versions

> Previous versions of MongoDB supported building indexes either in the foreground or background. Foreground index builds were fast and produced more efficient index data structures, but required blocking all read-write access to the parent database of the collection being indexed for the duration of the build. Background index builds were slower and had less efficient results, but allowed read-write access to the database and its collections during the build process.